# Can I save some time from typing "optirun"?

Tags: graphics, bumblebee

As title, I've installed BUMBLEBEE and now my NVidia Graphics card is enabled. However, I have to type "optirun" before the command I want to executed (e.x. $ optirun openrave) to change the graphics card to the NVidia OPTIMUS one, and it sometimes cause some trouble if I don't. Is there any tip that I can automatically change the Graphics Card mode to the NVidia OPTIMUS one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install the program `alacarte`, from where you can edit the execute commands for your program links (those you usually access programs with if you start them through your Desktop Environment).

So, if you want a game, let's say teeworlds, to always use your high performance graphics mode, you open alacarte, go to Games, then on teeworld. Then you click on "edit" and set the command from `teeworlds` to `optirun teeworlds`. Now teeworlds will use the high performance graphics mode whenever you start it through the dash, the Unity Launcher, the gnome-shell, e.g. but not if you execute `teeworlds` from the terminal or the command prompt (Alt+F2)